# Antipodal vertices in spectral graph embeddings

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, eigenvalues, spectral-graph-theory, graph-distance

Suppose your are given an *antipodal* graph $G=(V,E)$, that is, for every vertex $v\in V$ there is a unique maximally distant vertex $v'\in V$.

Under which condistions does the following hold:

> If $\theta_2$ denotes the second-largest eigenvalue of $G$ (i.e., of its adjacency matrix), then for every $\theta_2$-eigenvector $u\in\Bbb R^V$ we have $u_v=-u_{v'}$ for all $v\in V$.

For example, is this true if $G$

- is [walk-regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walk-regular_graph), (resp. vertex-transitive)
- is 1-walk-regular (resp. vertex- and edge-transitive, or arc-transitive),
- is [distance-regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-regular_graph) (resp. distance-transitive), or
- has a symmetry $\phi\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ mapping $v\mapsto v'$ for all $v\in V$.

Especially in the last case I can imagine that we have $u_v = \pm u_{v'}$ for all $v\in V$ and eigenvectors $u\in \smash{\Bbb R^V}$ of $G$ (not necessarily to $\theta_2$).
But I am specifically interested in the case $\theta_2$ and whether we then always have the negative sign.

Comment: Do you have any evidence/heuristics for why this should hold in some cases? Also what is special about $\theta_2$?

Comment: @AntoineLabelle My intuition comes from spectral embeddings of $G$, where you assign points in Euclidean space to the vertices of $G$, and you do this by somehow using the eigenvectors of $G$ to some eigenvalue. It seems to be common intuition, that the $\theta_2$-embedding is "as expanded as possible" (imagine the vertices as repelling each other, but the edges keeping them together, and then the $\theta_2$-embedding is an equilibrium configuration under these condition). And to be as expanded as possible, it is plausible that antipodal vertices are embedded opposite to each other.

Comment: @AntoineLabelle My evidence is that it holds for all the graphs I have checken (e.g. the skeletons of regular polytopes, but also many others).